# Need advice for getting data from remote with asynctask

Tags: android, json, api, android-asynctask

I am new on android programming. Before asking my question, here is my application logic;

- main screen
- - news screen ( need remote data with api )
- - weather screen ( need remote data with api )
- - exchange rates screen ( need remote data with api )
- - etc...  ( need remote data with api )

all apis have different urls, but they are all on my server, i can combine in 1 json file if its needed.

So the question is,
in what way i have to get data and show to user?

scenarios;
1 - at first, in loading screen, i can get all data and show when needed in different activities
2 - i can get data when the related activity loaded

and also, where should ı place the get data methods, because I don't want application request data everytime activity is loaded. Is it better if I cache data json file to device for every 1 hour (if cache is old, request new one, or user can update manually)?

Comment: if there is a sample code you can suggest, it will be good, i can get ideas.

Comment: You can use retrofit and setup it to use rxJava + caching (database or file or does not matter)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i suggest you use RX and Room as local DB.

On app startup load remote data with rx and save it to db.

Withing those screens use ViewModel to listen database node changes and load data.